# Calculated Column Count in SAP HANA

Tags: data-modeling, calculated-columns, hana

I have a table with fields ID, Status and Changed Date like below:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkpnX.png)

How to create a Calculated Column wherein I should the count like:
`Open       = 1
In progress = 1
Completed  = 1`

i.e., we should get the final status count of the ID.
Instead I'm getting the count like:
`Open       = 3
Inprogress = 2
Completed  = 1`

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The picture you linked shows that the table contains rows with a column STATUS that contains one of the three values you mentioned. Why do you need a calculated column to get the count for these different STATUSes? Why not just use a count(*) and group by the STATUS??

Comment: Each ID can have different status, I need the count of final status for each ID.

Comment: Ok, and how do you rank the different status? Which status is "final"? Please provide an example of the result you want to see.

Comment: I should rank just based on the text "Completed","In Progress" or "Open".In the above table, Final Status of ID 1 is InProgress, similarly for ID 2 its Completed. I can make use of last Changed Date also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the answer for [SQL query to fetch OrderID, transactionID, Status based on transaction status which is Char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096084/sql-query-to-fetch-orderid-transactionid-status-based-on-transaction-status-wh) which is basically your requirement.

Comment: Yes, it is similar!! I'll try this. Thank you